# THREE.LineSegments subclass visible but not being rendered

Tags: three.js

I have a LineSegments *subclass* object (using BufferGeometry) that is added to a scene (confirmed by logging) and has visible set to true. The original code did not subclass and rendered just fine. Is the fact that I subclassed LineSegments preventing it from rendering?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: It's possible, but hard to say without seeing your code.
Make sure you're using latest three.js etc.